# Undetermined coefficients in system of differential equations - what to guess?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations like this:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{aligned} 
x'&= x-4y +1\\ 
y'&=-x+y+e^{-t}
\end{aligned} 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I have found the complimentary solution (eigenvalues are -1 and 3), but I'm having a hard time finding the particular solution. I have tried guessing $$e^{at}(v_1+v_2t) $$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are vectors, but when I use the method of undetermined coefficients (yes we have to use this method) and construct the equations to find the coefficients, everything is fine but I am left with only one term with $e^{-t}$ as a factor, so I get $1/e^{-t}=0$ or $e^{-t}=0$. Am I guessing the wrong particular solution? Or I am supposed to just ignore this equation?

Comment: How about trying (constants are vectors of course) $$y_p = a + b~ e^{-t} + c~ t ~e^{-t}$$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{aligned} 
x'&= x-4y +1\\ 
y'&=-x+y+e^{-t}
\end{aligned} 
\end{array}
\right.
\implies X'=AX+e^{-t}\binom 01 +\binom 1 0 
$$
$$X_h=C_1e^{-t}\binom 21 +C_2e^{3t}\binom {-2}1$$
Since you already have $e^{-t}$ in the general solution of the system you should as Moo has suggested try this:

$$ X_p=K_1te^{-t}+K_2e^{-t}+K_3 $$

***Another approach..***

Summing $L_1+2L_2$

$$x'+2y'=-(x+2y)+1+2e^{-t}$$
Substitute $z=x+2y$
$$z'=-z+1+2e^{-t}$$
$$ze^t=\int e^t+2dt$$
$$x+2y=e^{-t}(e^t+2t+K_1)$$
$$\boxed{
\begin{cases}
x(t)=1-2y+e^{-t}(2t+K_1)\\
y'=-x+y+e^{-t}
\end{cases}}
$$
Easy to solve now

Comment: Yes true @moo I just added it as another approach since you have already given a hint